# Finding \$\small K\$ for a given \$\small\zeta\$ value when \$\omega_n\$ (frequency) is not given

Tags: control-system, root-locus

Here \$\omega_n\$ (frequency) is not given.

Then upon plotting the Root Locus, how will we find \$\small K\$ at  \$\small\zeta = 0.5\$ if we're not using a graph sheet and want to find everything mathematically?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the required zeta values are 0 and 0.5?

Comment: ω ≠ W. [filler]

Comment: For \$\zeta=0\$, this occurs when the radial line on the imaginary axis, or just find the gain as which the root locus intersects with the imaginary axis. For \$\zeta=0.5\$, you need to plot it in Matlab and search the intersection of the radial line with the root locus. In my code, this occurs at \$K=112\$ and for \$\zeta=0, K=443\$